# Warning: Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer

Tags: php, symfony

I fully converted my project from Symfony 3.3 to 6.1, it was an insane jump and I had to go through nearly the entire codebase. However, with all the great new additions to Symfony 6.1 (compared to 3.3) I'm happy that I spend the time doing it.

However, when I'm running it on my webserver, I get a warning; `Warning: Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer`. This does cause an Exception.

This warning is thrown when I try to 'unserialize' a property of an entity class. The database field is just a serialized stdClass basically. However, when I try unserializing it I get the error. The code is simply;

```
/**
 * @return Cart
 */
public function getCart()
{
    return unserialize($this->cart);
}
```

I have the feeling that when calling $this->cart after retrieving the entity from the database that its type is an incomplete class. However, I still need to unserialize it in order to use it. But the incomplete class type has no unserializer (also no serializer I assume). Do I need to 'cast' it in a way for it to work? (I tried some thing, but $this->cart is a string and $this->getCart() returns a Cart object).

**EDIT**:

I have found the resaon for the incorrect unserialization. My default namespace changed from AppBundle to App\Controller\AppBundle. However, my database contains the 'old' namespaces. What would be the best way to fix this?

Comment: The content when var_dumping $this->cart is; `string(305149) "O:31:"AppBundle\Interact\Compare\Cart":42:....`

Comment: "What would be the best way to fix this?" - why not use aliases?

Comment: Thanks for your response! How would that work? Are there options within `serialize` for that?

Comment: https://php.net/class_alias could help

Comment: Thanks for your response!

`        var_dump(class_alias('App\Controller\AppBundle\Interact\Compare\Cart', 'AppBundle\Interact\Compare\Cart'));
        var_dump(get_declared_classes());
        return unserialize($this->cart);`

Doing this should register the class alias. That part returns `true`, `get_declared_classes` shows `string(31) "appbundle\interact\compare\cart"`, lowercase. However `unserialize` still makes it an incomplete class. Am I doing something wrong? Or is it case-sensitive?